# Subsetting columns of a data frame that are stored into variables

Tags: python

I have a data frame (a .txt from R) that looks like this:

> ```
>  my_sample   my_coord1    my_coord2     my_cl     
>      A          0.34         0.12         1
>      B          0.2          1.11         1
>      C          0.23         0.10         1
>      D          0.9          0.34         2
>      E          0.21         0.6          2 
>     ...         ...          ...         ...
> ```

Using python I would like to extract columns 2 and 3 and put them into a variable as well as I would like to put column 4 into another variable. In R is: `my_var1 =  mydf[,c(2:3)]` and `my_var2 =  mydf[,4]`. I don't know how to do this in python but I tried:

> ```
>     mydf = open("mydf.txt", "r")
>     print(mydf.read())
>     lines = mydf.readlines() 
>           for line in lines:
>           sline = line.split(' ')  
>     print(sline) 
>     mydf.close()
> ```

But I don't know how to save into a variable each subsetting.
I know it seems a quite simple question but I'm a newbie in the field.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `read_table` from pandas in order to deal with tabular data file. The code

```
import pandas as pd

mydf = pd.read_table('mydf.txt',delim_whitespace = True)

my_var1 = mydf[['my_coord1','my_coord2']]

my_var2 = mydf['my_cl']
```